# How to make a content management system to load webpages without a PHP loader and its query strings?

Tags: php, mediawiki, url-parameters, clean-urls

I have a MediaWiki 1.35.2 Hebrew website which is principally all core; I host that website on a shared Apache, Nginx (as reverse proxy), PHP and MySQL hosting environment.

The default behavior of MediaWiki is to load any webpage with the PHP loader* `index.php` and at least one query string;

The MediaWiki phenomenon I have described often raises errors in Google Pagespeed Insights about *too many resources* which consume loading time (maybe it's better to load these informally without query strings) and it also makes my URLs "long" instead "short" (i.e. without using this `index.php` method) when they are already long because of Right-To-Left language Encoding.

For some reason/s I have a very hard time finding my way in the following MediaWiki guides on how to get shorter URLs without `index.php` and its query strings (guides that include explicitly outdated parts and/or many warnings and exceptions):

- [Manual:Short URL](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL)
- [Manual:Short URL/Apache](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL/Apache)

Comment: I would expect a MediaWiki specific solution to this question.   It requires 2 pieces: 1. Implementing a front controller (typically with rewrite rules) 2. Changing all the links in the CMS.   The solutions for the first problem are pretty generic, but the solutions for the second problem are very CMS specific.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller oh my gosh, I have about 850 webpages there but none has a "slug"/"alias" to any of these; each page's URL is solely created "on the fly" by MediaWiki so after I have the solution to the first problem, I think that MediaWiki itself would take care of the rest, won't it?

Comment: Most CMS have a setting for it but I've never used media wiki myself, so I don't know what it has.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do short URLs obligate 301 redirects?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/134521/do-short-urls-obligate-301-redirects)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I am not sure, but I posted both; anyway, I have lost any desire to further discuss the matter here.